Creating an AsyncStream from AVSpeechSynthesizer.write callback
I'm trying to turn the results of AVSpeechSynthesizer.write into an AsyncStream. I'm wondering what the cleanest way is to ensure that the AVSpeechSynthesizer stays alive until the stream is finished
Here's the code I initially wrote:
func toSpeachStream(utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) -> AsyncStream<AVAudioPCMBuffer> {
    return AsyncStream { continuation in
        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    
        synthesizer.write(utterance, toBufferCallback: { buffer in
            guard let buffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
                return
            }
            
            continuation.yield(buffer)
    
            if buffer.frameCapacity <= 1 { // Check if finished
                continuation.finish()
            }
        })
    }
}

This doesn't seem to work. I believe the problem is that synthesizer is destroyed before the write callbacks finish. The result is an empty stream that we wait on forever
My current solution is to hold onto a reference to an AVSpeechSynthesizer until the entire stream has been consumed, something like this:
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
for await buff in toSpeachStream(synthesizer, utterance) {
    ...
}

// Make sure the synthesizer stays alive until the stream is done
synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate) 

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this? I'd prefer keeping the simple signature of toSpeachStream

How about creating your own AsyncSequence class that wraps an AsyncStream? That class can then store a reference to the speech synthesiser. toSpeachStream can return some AsyncSequence<AVAudioPCMBuffer> to hide this implementation detail.

You can move the instantiation of the speech synthesizer out of this function. For example, I might just write a function that returns the AsyncStream as a method of the AVSpeechSynthesizer:
extension AVSpeechSynthesizer {
    func buffers(for utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) -> AsyncStream<AVAudioPCMBuffer> {
        AsyncStream { continuation in
            write(utterance) { buffer in
                guard let buffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
                    return
                }

                continuation.yield(buffer)

                if buffer.frameCapacity <= 1 { // Check if finished
                    continuation.finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Then you can do can instantiate the synthesizer where you iterate through the buffers, ensuring that the AVSpeechSynthesizer is not deallocated until you are done iterating through the asynchronous sequence:
func processBuffers(for utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) async {
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    for await buffer in synthesizer.buffers(for: utterance) {
        …
    }
}


FWIW, I might consider an AsyncThrowingStream:
extension AVSpeechSynthesizer {
    enum BuffersError: Error {
        case notPcmBuffer
    }

    func buffers(for utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) -> AsyncThrowingStream<AVAudioPCMBuffer, Error> {
        .init { continuation in
            write(utterance) { buffer in
                guard let buffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
                    continuation.finish(throwing: BuffersError.notPcmBuffer)
                    return
                }

                continuation.yield(buffer)

                if buffer.frameCapacity <= 1 { // Check if finished
                    continuation.finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And
func processBuffers(for utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) async throws {
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    for try await buffer in synthesizer.buffers(for: utterance) {
        …
    }
}

